# i18n.merge_file can't translate desktop file

Tags: meson-build

I'm trying to convert autotools project to Meson and stuck on translation of desktop file.
There is no problem to get all .mo files created.
POTFILES and LINGUAS are in 'po' folder as per [manual](https://mesonbuild.com/Localisation.html).
Only problem is i18n.merge_file is not generating file with translations.
My meson.build looks like

```
    ...
    package = meson.project_name()
    i18n = import('i18n')
    add_project_arguments('-DGETTEXT_PACKAGE="@0@"'.format(package), language:'c')
    subdir('po')
    i18n.merge_file(
      input: 'data/clipit.desktop.in',
      output: 'clipit.desktop',
      type: 'desktop',
      po_dir: 'po',
      install: true,
      install_dir: '/usr/share/applications'
    )
    ...
```

po/meson.build

```
    i18n.gettext(package, preset: 'glib')
```

clipit.desktop.in

```
[Desktop Entry]
_Name=ClipIt
_Comment=Clipboard Manager
Icon=clipit-trayicon-offline
Exec=clipit
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=GTK;GNOME;Application;Utility;
```

After ninja install output is:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Icon=clipit-trayicon-offline
Exec=clipit
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=GTK;GNOME;Application;Utility;
```

It is based on (https://mesonbuild.com/Porting-from-autotools.html) but also tried to follow 'eye of gnome' meson.build. No luck.
Current version of code on [github](https://github.com/afelinczak/ClipIt/tree/support-meson).

**Edit:**
Leaving snippet that can be used, as meson documentation don't cover using intltool.

```
custom_target('clipit.desktop',
  input : 'data/clipit.desktop.in',
  output : 'clipit.desktop',
  command: [intltool_merge, '-d', '-u', join_paths(meson.source_root(), 'po'), '@INPUT@', '@OUTPUT@'],
  install : true,
  install_dir : get_option('datadir') / 'applications')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why this doesn't work, is that this isn't valid input to gettext :)
The underscore at the start of the `_Name` and `_Comment` fields are because of `intltool`, another translation tool similar to gettext. To solve this, just remove the underscore of those fields. This will work for `.desktop` files. For more information, you can also take a few hints from https://wiki.gnome.org/MigratingFromIntltoolToGettext

On a side note, you shouldn't direct install to '/usr/share/applications', since someone might want to choose a custom prefix or datadir (see [Meson - Built-in options](https://mesonbuild.com/Builtin-options.html) for more info). It's better to use `install_dir: get_option('datadir') / 'applications'`.

Comment: Thank you so much, I finished with using custom_target as initially I don't want to touch exisiting autotools scripts.